# Celluloid SupervisionGroup does not work

Tags: ruby, celluloid

I write the following script in order to understand Celluloid.

```
require 'celluloid/current'

class Processor
  include Celluloid

  def perfom(number)
    puts "#{number} ... (#{Thread.current}) ..."
    sleep(number%3)
    puts "Launch finish!"
    return number
  end
end

pool = Processor.pool(size: 3)

futures = (1..7).map do |i|
  pool.future(:perfom, i)
end
puts futures.map(&:value)

pool.terminate
```

All work fine and i want to avoid to call the terminate on the pool.

So i try to use supervisor but it raise me `uninitialized constant Celluloid::SupervisionGroup`

After search I find this (in deprecated folder) : (https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-supervision/blob/master/spec/celluloid/deprecate/supervision/supervision_group_spec.rb)

I wanted to make work something like :

```
supervisor = Celluloid::SupervisionGroup.run!
pool       = supervisor.pool(Processor, size: 3, as: :worker)

futures = (1..7).map do |i|
  pool[:worker].future(:perfom, i)
end
puts futures.map(&:value)
```

How can I make work future, supervisor and pool with the new system?

Answer (score 2):

**Celluloid::SupervisionGroup** is renamed to **Celluloid::Supervision::Container**

see https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/DEPRECATION-WARNING